# Java Substring by Keyword

Tags: java, string, substring, match

I have to make separate Strings from one single String.

For example given the String:

```
.*C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}T.{0}T.{2}T.{0}G.{8}T.{7}A.{7}T.{2}T.{12}A.{5}T.{4}T.{45}A.{1}A.{10}G.{19}A.{25}T.{3}A.{1}A.{4}G.{1}A.{2}A.{29}A.{0}C.{15}A.{1}C.{1}A.{6}T.{3}G.{5}T.{0}T.{0}C.{3}G.{2}C.{1}G.{4}G.{1}G.*
```

I have to create a HashSet with the following content:

```
.*C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}T.*
.*A.{2}T.{0}T.{0}T.*
.*T.{0}T.{0}T.{2}T.*
.*T.{0}T.{2}T.{0}G.*
...
```

The elements are formed by taking 4 of the entries from the original string and creating a smaller string from them. Then you move one entry along in the original string and repeat.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how the input and the output relate

Comment: Hi All Output information is from Input .  First for Character of Input is C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}T and next character start from A.{2} so cut A.{2}T.{0}T.{0}T .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a string, representing a list of elements, and turn it into a set of overlapping shorter lists of elements. You can do this by having a method which returns the elements from the list and then a sliding window which selects sets of elements to display:

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ACGT]\\.\\{\\d+\\}");

public static List<String> extract(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        result.add(matcher.group(0));
    }

    return result;
}

public static Set<String> compose(List<String> elements, int window) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= elements.size() - window; i++) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(".*");
        for (int j = i; j < i + window; j++) {
            builder.append(elements.get(j));
        }
        // This strips the final quantifier turning:
        // .*C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}T.{0}
        // into
        // .*C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}T
        builder.delete(builder.lastIndexOf("."), builder.length());

        builder.append(".*");
        result.add(builder.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can check this with the following method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = ".*C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}T.{0}T.{2}T.{0}G.{8}T.{7}A.{7}";

    Set<String> result = compose(extract(input), 4);

    // The result will contain
    // ".*C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}T.*"
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much when I try to debug your code I get results .*T.{0}T.{0}T.{2}T.{0}.* .. This which supposed to be .*T.{0}T.{0}T.{2}T.*

Comment: Oh There is one issue if C.{7}T.{2}T.{12}A. Then Pattern cut 12->2 only allow one digit so It will show C.{7}T.{2}T.{2}A

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = ".*C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}T.{0}T.{2}T.{0}G.{8}T.{7}A.{7}T.{2}T.{12}A.{5}T.{4}T.{45}A.{1}A.{10}G.{19}A.{25}T.{3}A.{1}A.{4}G.{1}A.{2}A.{29}A.{0}C.{15}A.{1}C.{1}A.{6}T.{3}G.{5}T.{0}T.{0}C.{3}G.{2}C.{1}G.{4}G.{1}G.*";
    String[] array = s.split("}");

    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length-3 ; i++) {
        String firstElement = array[i].startsWith(".*") ? array[i].substring(2) : array[i];
        String lastElement =  array[i+2]+"}"+array[i+3].substring(0,1)+".*" ;
        String element = ".*"+firstElement+"}"+array[i+1]+"}"+lastElement;
        result.add(element);
        System.out.println(element);
    }

    //Your result are in the Set result
}
}
```

Comment: Your strings only have three of the elements in, but in the examples he provides there are 4 elements. For example your first result generated is `.*C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}.*` when it should be `.*C.{0}A.{2}T.{0}T.*`

Comment: I see, you're right. I complete the code immediately.